# Unexpected output in inheritance

Tags: java

I got a certain code from Java certification question and its output kind of baffled me. Here is the code

```
class Baap {
    public int h = 4;
    public int getH() {
        System.out.println("Baap " + h);
        return h;
    }
}

class Beta extends Baap {
    public int h = 44;
    public int getH() {
        System.out.println("Beta " + h);
        return h;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Baap b = new Beta();
        System.out.println(b.h + " " + b.getH());
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
Beta 44
4 44
```

I was expecting it to be:

```
4 Beta 44
44
```

Why does it produce this output?

Comment: When you run the line `System.out.println(b.h + " " + b.getH());` you are passing a single `String` to `System.out.println` and the `getH` call must complete first, otherwise there is no `String` to pass to `System.out.println`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output consists of two parts:

1. A line printed inside `getH()`
2. A line printed inside `main()`

The line produced by `getH()` is printed before the line produced by `main()`, because `getH()` must finish before `main` finishes constructing its output.

Now the output should be clear: even though `4` is *evaluated* before the call to `getH` is made inside `main`, it gets printed *after* `getH()` has returned.

Answer (score 3):

Before `System.out.println(b.h + " " + b.getH())` can print anything, `b.h + " " + b.getH()` must be evaluated.

`b.getH()` calls `Beta`'s method (since it overrides the base class method) which prints `Beta 44`.

Then `b.h` (4) is appended to the result of `b.getH()` (44) and `println` prints `4 44`.

`b.h` returns the value of the `h` variable of the base class (4), since the compile time type of `b` is `Baap` (the base class), and variables cannot be overridden. On the other hand, `b.getH()` returns the value of the `h` variable of the sub-class (44), since methods can be overridden.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is here in the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7.2):

> 15.7.2. Evaluate Operands before Operation
>
> The Java programming language guarantees that every operand of an operator (except the conditional operators &&, ||, and ? :) appears to be fully evaluated before any part of the operation itself is performed.

Your method `getH()` has a **side effect**, and that one can be *observed* before the expression invoking that method is fully evaluated.

As there are **two** parts:

```
String baapBetaStr = b.h + " " + b.getH();
```

A) a string concatenation

B) a method invocation

And of course, in order to concatenate that string, all parts of that expression need to be evaluated ("ran") first!

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Baap b = new Beta();
        System.out.print(b.h + " ");
        System.out.print(b.getH());
    }
```

Comment: You need to understand the process of function calling.

Comment: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.